# When creating a boolean series from subsetting a df, what does index-subsetting in the same line filter for?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

I'm experimenting with pandas and noticed something that seemed odd.

If you have a boolean series defined as an object, you can then subset that object by index numbers, e.g.,

From df 'ah'
[image], creating
creating this boolean series, 'tah'
via

```
tah = ah['_merge']=='left_only'
```

[image]

This boolean series could be index-subset like this:

```
tah[0:1]
```

yielding:
[image]

Yet if I tried to do this all in one line

```
ah['_merge']=='left_only'[0:1]
```

I get an unexpected output, where the boolean series is neither sliced nor seems to correspond to the subsetted-column:
[image]

I've been experimenting and can't seem to determine what, in the all-in-on-line [0:1] is slicing/filtering-for. Any clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes.

Comment: `'left_only'[0:1]` is slicing the string `"left_only"` to `"l"`. Since none of the values are `"l"`, it returns `False` for the boolean array. I think what you want instead is `(ah['_merge']=='left_only')[0:1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are equating string's 'left_over' index of 0 (letter 'l') and this yields false result in every row and since 'l' is not equal to 'left_over' nor to 'both', it prints all a column of false booleans.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(ah['_merge']=='left_only')[0:1]` as [MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426065/mattdmo) mentionned in the comments.

Or you can also use [**`pandas.Series.iloc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) with a slice object to select the elements you need based on their postion/index in your dataframe.

```
(ah['_merge']=='left_only').iloc[0:1]
```

Both of commands will return `True` since the first row of your dataframe has a `'left_only'` type of merge.